# How to return to specific point in for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a series of nested loops that cycles through a number of excel files, and based on checks on the content, adds the content to a list of dataframes.

At a certain condition I need to break out of the current loop, not add to the data frame list, and continue parsing the next excel. Unfortunately I cannot figure out how to setup the loop in order to accomplish my desired behavior.

Code is as follows currently. I've added comments explaining what behavior I'm looking for.

```
for name in folder_names:
path = rf'I:\PATH\{name}'
file_list = [f for f in glob.glob(path+"/*.xlsx")]
df_list = []
for f in file_list: #if a break event is triggered, I need to return here.
    xl = pd.ExcelFile(f)
    if len(xl.sheet_names) == 1:
        wb = load_workbook(f, data_only = True)
        sh = wb.worksheets[0]
        ColNames = {}
        Current  = 0
        for COL in sh.iter_cols(1, sh.max_column):
            ColNames[COL[0].value] = Current
            Current += 1
        for row_cells in sh.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=len(sh['D'])):
            if row_cells[ColNames['XXXX ID']].fill.start_color.index != '00000000':
                path_file.write(f+'\n') 
                break                
        df_list.append(pd.read_excel(f)) #if a break event is triggered, I need this line to NOT be executed
```

Logic desired:

If current excel has only 1 sheet then check if Column D has no cell fill color, if true add to data frame list, if false, return to next excel file in loop.

Comment: You will need a flag, because the break only terminates the inner loop.  Something like `keep_file = True` then at the break, use `keep_file = False`, and you can put your append command in an `if keep_file` block.  Or now that you are outside the loop you could do `if not keep_file: continue` which goes to the next iteration of your `for`

Comment: @RufusVS A `for ... else ...` statement would do the job. Just skip the appending if we hit `break`. So it would be `else: df_list.append(...)` and that's all.

Comment: @Asocia Thank you! I have never used the `for..else` construct in Python and I had a feeling it would work here.  But having never really used it, I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a boolean to check whether you broke out of the loop or not. It should look something like this (feel free to change boolean name):

```
for name in folder_names:
    path = rf'I:\PATH\{name}'
    file_list = [f for f in glob.glob(path+"/*.xlsx")]
    df_list = []
    for f in file_list: #if a break event is triggered, I need to return here.
        xl = pd.ExcelFile(f)
        if len(xl.sheet_names) == 1:
            wb = load_workbook(f, data_only = True)
            sh = wb.worksheets[0]
            ColNames = {}
            Current  = 0
            loop_broken = False
            for COL in sh.iter_cols(1, sh.max_column):
                ColNames[COL[0].value] = Current
                Current += 1
            for row_cells in sh.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=len(sh['D'])):
                if row_cells[ColNames['XXXX ID']].fill.start_color.index != '00000000':
                    path_file.write(f+'\n') 
                    loop_broken = True
                    break                
            if (not loop_broken): df_list.append(pd.read_excel(f)) #if a break event is triggered, I need this line to NOT be executed
```

Answer (score 5):

You can write a `for ... else ...` statement.

```
for i in range(5):
    print(i)
    if i > 2:
        print("Hit break")
        break
else:
    print("I didn't hit a break inside the loop")
```

```
0
1
2
3
Hit break
```

```
for i in range(5):
    print(i)
    if i > 2:
        pass
else:
    print("I didn't hit a break inside the loop")
```

```
0
1
2
3
4
I didn't hit a break inside the loop
```

So to answer your question, you just need to do this:

```
...
for row_cells in sh.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=len(sh['D'])):
    if row_cells[ColNames['XXXX ID']].fill.start_color.index != '00000000':
        path_file.write(f+'\n') 
        break
else: # <- add this line and indent your code
    df_list.append(pd.read_excel(f))
```

Answer (score 1):

adding a flag would solve it:

```
flag = False
for x in range(10):
    if x == 2:
        flag = True
        break
if flag:
     # dont do sth
     pass
else:
     # do sth
     pass
```